# Can a .NET oData DataService force filtering child records?

Tags: web-services, odata, wcf-data-services, dataservice

This should be a simple scenario - I have a data model with a parent/child relationship.  For example's sake, let's say it's Orders and OrderDetails - 1 Order -> many OrderDetails.

I'd like to expose the model via oData using a standard DataService, but with a few limitations.

First, I should only see my Orders.  That's simple enough using EntitySetRights.ReadSingle and a QueryInterceptor to make sure the order is in fact mine.

So far, so good!  But how can the associated OrderDetail records be exposed in the oData feed in a way where I can read OrderDetails for a **specific** (read single) Order without giving access to the entire OrderDetails table?

In other words, I want to allow reading **my details**

```
myUrl.com/OrderService.svc/Orders(5)/OrderDetails  <-- Good! My order is #5
```

**but not everyone's details**

```
myUrl.com/OrderService.svc/OrderDetails  <-- Danger, Scarry, Keep Out!
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

This is so called "containment" - your sample exactly described here: http://data.uservoice.com/forums/72027-wcf-data-services-feature-suggestions/suggestions/1012615-support-containment-hierarchical-models-in-odata?ref=title
WCF Data Services doesn't support this out of the box yet.

It is theoretically possible to implement such restriction with a custom LINQ provider. In your LINQ implementation you could detect the expansion (not that hard) and in that case allow it. But you could prevent queries to the entity set itself (also rather easy to recognize). For more details of how the LINQ expressions look plese refere to this series: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vitek/archive/2010/02/25/data-services-expressions-part-1-intro.aspx

It depends on what provider you wanted to use originally. If you had a custom provider already this is not that hard. If you had a reflection based provider, it is possible to layer this on top. If you had EF, this might be rather tricky (not sure if it's even possible).